# QGIS and plugin Catalog on the fly

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I upgraded QGIS from 3.16 to 3.22. Everything works fine, except that I’m not able to install the plugin « Catalog on the fly ».

I always have an error:

```
TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with layerWasAdded(QgsMapLayer*)
```

Did someone was able to install this plugin on QGIS 3.22.8?

Comment: try to remove this line on the installation on the plugin on your computer : https://github.com/lmotta/catalog-on-the-fly/blob/4a680c56aa05f2713af856d800e74fc25cab2304/catalogotf.py#L533

Comment: It works perfectly!